# Propel ORM: How to use own brackets in where clause

Tags: sql, database, propel

i use propel for database interaction. Now i have to create a query like

```
SELECT data FROM values WHERE a=1 AND (vis=1 or (vis=0 AND userID=5));
```

I create a propel object from the table "values".

```
$p = new ValuesQuery()::create
   ->filterByA(1)
   ->filterByVis(1)
   ->_or()
   ->filterByVis(0)
   ->filterByUserId(5)
   ->findOne();
```

Propel generates the following SQL-Query which mostly makes sense:

```
SELECT data FROM values WHERE a=1 AND (vis=1 or vis=0) AND userID=5;
```

How can i fix this? Is it possible to say propel what it should put in brackets?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: As per my answer to @kirilloid, I think you're looking for the combine() query operator. I've not used it, but check the docs - I think they're quite good generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @halfer said, read the following documentation on how to combine several conditions: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#combining_several_conditions

Answer (score 1):

Playing with next tool may not only answer your particular question, but also help you understand, how complicated conditions are built.

http://propel.jondh.me.uk/criteria/analyse

Comment: I'm always pleased when my Propel generator gets published `:)` - but it only generates Criteria expressions, which will be phased out in Propel 2.0. I suspect the OP is looked for the `combine()` operator.

Comment: I just put his query into that generator and it produces some meaningful output =)

Comment: Yeah, it'll certainly work with Propel 1.x - one or two buglets aside! `;-)`